# Como invertir matrices en numpy

Tags: python, array, numpy, netcdf4

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy tratando de invertir la matriz de mi codigo cuando calculo el dato medio anual. (pp_av = np.mean(pp[:,:,:],axis = 0) he probado varias formas y ninguna me invierte las columnas (no se si es la palabra correcta), me podrían ayudar, ya que si no logro invertir estas columnas no me deja graficar y me marca este error: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (240,185) (185,240). Como se ve la derecha quisiera que la matriz pp_av se viese al reves primero 185, luego 240

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from  mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import warnings

data = Dataset(r'C:\Users\ferfo\Desktop\2001-2020.nc4')
print(data.variables.keys())

pp = data.variables['precipitationCal'][:]
pp_av = np.mean(pp[:,:,:],axis = 0)



warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

plt.figure(num=1, figsize=(5,4))

map = Basemap(projection="merc", resolution='i', llcrnrlat=-38.496, urcrnrlat=-19.951, llcrnrlon=-66.885, urcrnrlon=-42.891) 
map.drawcoastlines(color="black") 
map.drawstates()
map.drawcountries()
lons,lats = np.meshgrid(data.variables['lon'][:], data.variables['lat'][:]) 
x,y = map(lons, lats)
pp_plot = map.contourf(x, y, pp_av, cmap=plt.cm.rainbow) 
cb = map.colorbar(pp_plot, "bottom", size="10%", pad="10%", extend = 'both')
cb.set_label(u"Precipitation \u1983")
plt.title("PP Media 2001-2020")
plt.annotate('IMGER',(-178,-88), fontsize=6)
plt.show() 

plt.savefig("cruts_global.png")
```

Comment: Si por invertir quieres decir "transponer", la transpuesta de la matriz `A` la obtienes escribiendo `A.T`

Comment: Seria mas claro si colocas una matriz modelo y luego la invertida.

Comment: Acabo de subir una foto para que vean a que me refiero, seria que en la matriz pp_av me quede primero el 185 y luego 240

Comment: ¿Has probado `pp_av.T` como indicaba en otro comentario?

Comment: Si probe, pero no ha funcionado. Probe varios comandos para transponer y ninguno me deja